# Scikit Learn multiclass classification (perfect results)

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

Hello i'm very new to scikit learn and i'm trying to do some text multiclass classification, i'm following [this](http://marcobonzanini.com/2015/01/19/sentiment-analysis-with-python-and-scikit-learn/) tutorial.
My dataset has 4 classes `'fipdl', 'lna','m5s','pd'` , so i got 4 folder(one for class) each folder contains 120 txt files with about 25 rows of text(facebook statuses).
I use 90% of it for training , 10% for testing.
10% of my txt files names starts with 'ts' and i'm using these for testing.
so my code is :

```
import sys
import os
import time

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

def usage():
    print("Usage:")
    print("python %s <data_dir>" % sys.argv[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    usage()
    sys.exit(1)

data_dir = sys.argv[1]
classes = ['fipdl', 'lna','m5s','pd']

# Read the data
train_data = []
train_labels = []
test_data = []
test_labels = []

for curr_class in classes:
    dirname = os.path.join(data_dir, curr_class)
    for fname in os.listdir(dirname):
        with open(os.path.join(dirname, fname), 'r') as f:
            content = f.read()
            if fname.startswith('ts'):
                test_data.append(content)
                test_labels.append(curr_class)
                
            else:
                train_data.append(content)
                train_labels.append(curr_class)



# Create feature vectors
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5,
                             max_df = 0.8,
                             sublinear_tf=True,
                             use_idf=True)
train_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data)
test_vectors = vectorizer.transform(test_data)
# Perform classification with SVM, kernel=rbf
classifier_rbf = svm.SVC()
t0 = time.time()
classifier_rbf.fit(train_vectors, train_labels)
t1 = time.time()
prediction_rbf = classifier_rbf.predict(test_vectors)
t2 = time.time()
time_rbf_train = t1-t0
time_rbf_predict = t2-t1

# Perform classification with SVM, kernel=linear
classifier_linear = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
t0 = time.time()
classifier_linear.fit(train_vectors, train_labels)
t1 = time.time()
prediction_linear = classifier_linear.predict(test_vectors)
t2 = time.time()
time_linear_train = t1-t0
time_linear_predict = t2-t1

# Perform classification with SVM, kernel=linear
classifier_liblinear = svm.LinearSVC()
t0 = time.time()
classifier_liblinear.fit(train_vectors, train_labels)
t1 = time.time()
prediction_liblinear = classifier_liblinear.predict(test_vectors)
t2 = time.time()
time_liblinear_train = t1-t0
time_liblinear_predict = t2-t1

# Print results in a nice table
print("Results for SVC(kernel=rbf)")
print("Training time: %fs; Prediction time: %fs" % (time_rbf_train, time_rbf_predict))
print(classification_report(test_labels, prediction_rbf))
print("Results for SVC(kernel=linear)")
print("Training time: %fs; Prediction time: %fs" % (time_linear_train, time_linear_predict))
print(classification_report(test_labels, prediction_linear))
print("Results for LinearSVC()")
print("Training time: %fs; Prediction time: %fs" % (time_liblinear_train, time_liblinear_predict))
print(classification_report(test_labels, prediction_liblinear))
```

output :

```
Results for SVC(kernel=rbf)
Training time: 0.940005s; Prediction time: 0.055970s
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

      fipdl       1.00      1.00      1.00        11
        lna       1.00      1.00      1.00        11
        m5s       1.00      1.00      1.00        11
         pd       1.00      1.00      1.00        11

avg / total       1.00      1.00      1.00        44

Results for SVC(kernel=linear)
Training time: 0.941262s; Prediction time: 0.056382s
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

      fipdl       1.00      1.00      1.00        11
        lna       1.00      1.00      1.00        11
        m5s       1.00      1.00      1.00        11
         pd       1.00      1.00      1.00        11

avg / total       1.00      1.00      1.00        44

Results for LinearSVC()
Training time: 0.034038s; Prediction time: 0.000323s
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

      fipdl       1.00      1.00      1.00        11
        lna       1.00      1.00      1.00        11
        m5s       1.00      1.00      1.00        11
         pd       1.00      1.00      1.00        11

avg / total       1.00      1.00      1.00        44
```

Now the result seem too good to be true since every method gave me 1 of precision.
I think also would be nice to try to predict string passed by me instead of a test set,for do more tests, so i change the original code to this:

```
import sys
import os
import time

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

def usage():
    print("Usage:")
    print("python %s <data_dir>" % sys.argv[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        usage()
        sys.exit(1)

    data_dir = sys.argv[1]
    classes = ['fipdl', 'lna','m5s','pd']

    # Read the data
    train_data = []
    train_labels = []
    test_data = []
    test_labels = []
    
    for curr_class in classes:
        dirname = os.path.join(data_dir, curr_class)
        for fname in os.listdir(dirname):
            with open(os.path.join(dirname, fname), 'r') as f:
                content = f.read()
                if fname.startswith('ts'):
                    test_data.append(content)
                    test_labels.append(curr_class)
                    
                else:
                    train_data.append(content)
                    train_labels.append(curr_class)


    
    # Create feature vectors
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5,
                                 max_df = 0.8,
                                 sublinear_tf=True,
                                 use_idf=True)
    string = ['string to predict'] #my string
    vector = vectorizer.transform(string) #convert
    train_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data)
    
    test_vectors = vectorizer.transform(test_data)
    # Perform classification with SVM, kernel=rbf
    classifier_rbf = svm.SVC()
    t0 = time.time()
    classifier_rbf.fit(train_vectors, train_labels)
    t1 = time.time()
    prediction_rbf = classifier_rbf.predict(vector) #predict
    t2 = time.time()
    time_rbf_train = t1-t0
    time_rbf_predict = t2-t1

    # Perform classification with SVM, kernel=linear
    classifier_linear = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
    t0 = time.time()
    classifier_linear.fit(train_vectors, train_labels)
    t1 = time.time()
    prediction_linear = classifier_linear.predict(test_vectors)
    t2 = time.time()
    time_linear_train = t1-t0
    time_linear_predict = t2-t1

    # Perform classification with SVM, kernel=linear
    classifier_liblinear = svm.LinearSVC()
    t0 = time.time()
    classifier_liblinear.fit(train_vectors, train_labels)
    t1 = time.time()
    prediction_liblinear = classifier_liblinear.predict(test_vectors)
    t2 = time.time()
    time_liblinear_train = t1-t0
    time_liblinear_predict = t2-t1

    # Print results in a nice table
    print("Results for SVC(kernel=rbf)")
    print("Training time: %fs; Prediction time: %fs" % (time_rbf_train, time_rbf_predict))
    print(classification_report(test_labels, prediction_rbf))
    print("Results for SVC(kernel=linear)")
    print("Training time: %fs; Prediction time: %fs" % (time_linear_train, time_linear_predict))
    print(classification_report(test_labels, prediction_linear))
    print("Results for LinearSVC()")
    print("Training time: %fs; Prediction time: %fs" % (time_liblinear_train, time_liblinear_predict))
    print(classification_report(test_labels, prediction_liblinear))
```

but it fails with

```
ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [18 44]
```

i'm missing something? or maybe this is a totally wrong approach?
any help would be really appreciated,
thanks in advance Nico.

Comment: `vector = vectorizer.transform([string])`@Nicolò Cozzani

Comment: Right, thanks but it does not works,s 'klearn.utils.validation.NotFittedError: TfidfVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted.'

Comment: You create instance of vectorizer only once? Can you show the whole code? @Nicolò Cozzani

Comment: Sure i will edit the post, by the way i just those 3 lines to original code.

Comment: just added full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if i have not figured out yet why it give me perfect results, i've decided  to use a different approach for classify my text (with MultinomialNB) and test it with a string of my choice. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it but it works so i decided to post as answer:
(please note that not all the lines of code are necessary)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, f1_score
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB


string = sys.argv[1] #the string i'd like to predict
sets = load_files('scikit') #load my personal dataset




count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(sets.data)



tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(X_train_counts)
X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)


tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
X_train_tfidf.shape


clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, sets.target)
docs_new = [string]
X_new_counts = count_vect.transform(docs_new)
X_new_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(X_new_counts)
predicted = clf.predict(X_new_tfidf)

for doc, category in zip(docs_new, predicted):
     print('%r => %s' % (doc, sets.target_names[category])) #print result of prediction
```

then from console just run `script.py "string to predict"`

A lot of improvement can be done to this code, like dump the trained model, but  is good enough for my usage.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create feature vectors
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5,
                                 max_df = 0.8,
                                 sublinear_tf=True,
                                 use_idf=True)
    string = ['string to predict'] #my string
    vector = vectorizer.transform(string) #convert
    train_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data)
```

You creating new instance of vectorizer, and  before fitting it , you using `transform` method. Just change the order of two last rows, like this:

```
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5,
                                 max_df = 0.8,
                                 sublinear_tf=True,
                                 use_idf=True)
    string = ['string to predict'] #my string
    train_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data)
    vector = vectorizer.transform(string) #convert
```

Comment: This code is exactly the same of mine, and still not working

Comment: Change the order of two rows `vector = vectorizer.transform(string)` and `train_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data)`

Comment: still 'sklearn.utils.validation.NotFittedError: TfidfVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted.'